# When installing mysql workbench I get the following error

Tags: mysql

```
Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
                 Depends: libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a (>= 1:2.24.0) but 1:2.24.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libpcrecpp0 (>= 7.7) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.2 is to be installed
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.1-0ubuntu2) but it is a virtual package
                 Depends: mysql-workbench-data (= 6.0.8+dfsg-2) but 6.0.8+dfsg-2 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run this command that should fix package dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then run the installation command

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.6-1ubu1510-amd64.deb
```

(I'm supposing you downloaded `.deb` file from [mysql website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), you're running Ubuntu 15.10 and your terminal is in the same directory of mysql workbench installation file)

If you want more information about `apt-get` command or `dpkg` command you can read the manual running these commands:

```
man apt-get

man dpkg
```

---

I've just got the same installation issue it on my machine and I've resolved the problem in this way.

I hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Install gdebi, it lets you install local deb packages resolving and installing its dependencies.

```
apt-get install gdebi
```

After that install your MySQL `.deb` package with gdebi

```
gdebi package.deb
```